# How to select ComboBox value after Data filled from DataSource

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to set the selected value to a known value.  However, after InititializeComponent() has been called, the data is not yet filled in a databound Combobox so I can't set my selected value there.

Which event is triggered when the data has finished to be added in the combobox from the databound object ? Is there any other way you would suggest handling this ?

Many thanks

Comment: can't you set it in form_load?

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe to the

> DataSourceChanged

event of the ComboBox but if you do so you have to set DisplayMember and ValueMember first or you can't use ComboBox.SelectedValue.

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
comboBox1.DataSource = dataTable;
```